# About NDSolve with piecewise inputs

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I am trying to solve numerically two differential equations with NDSolve.

```
Equation1 = a'[x]/a[x] - Sqrt[(1/3)*( (1/2)*(f'[x])^2 + g[f[x]] )]
Equation2 = f''[x] + 3*(a'[x]/a[x])*f'[x] + D[g[f[x]], f[x]]
```

where `a[x]` and `f[x]` are both the functions I want to get, and where I want to define `g[f[x]]` as a Piecewise function of `f[x]`:

```
g[f[x]] = Piecewise[{{f[x]^2, x0 <= x <= a1}, {-n*f[x], a1 <= x <= a2}, {f[x]^2, x >= a2}}]
```

where `n` is a constant value.

The problem arises when I try to solve this equation numerically (let us assume e.g. `x0 = 0`, `a1 = 5000`, `a2 = 10000`, `xf = 10^6`):

```
nsol = NDSolve[{Equation1 == 0, Equation2 == 0, a[x0] == 1, f[x0] == K1, f'[x0] == -n*K1}, {a, f}, {x, x0, xf}, MaxSteps -> 10000000, PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 90]
```

with `K1` another number and `n` the same before defined. (Note that I have tried to simplify my notation here used for more generality).

Unfortunately, there appears the following mistake when computing:

> NDSolve::litarg: "To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in ... should literally match the independent variables."

I have already searched for similar threads as mine unsuccesfully. My specific question is the following one: how could I solve those differential equations dependent on `Piecewise` functions numerically, without needing to solve them each time for each separate interval of `x` as defined in `g[f[x]]`?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post to correct the (apparent) mistake where you used `EQ1` and `EQ2` in the `NDSolve` and defined `Equation1` and `Equation2`. Nonetheless, we still are going to need numerical values for `K`, et c. if we're going to be able to reproduce your problem (since as you probably know, changing coefficients in ODEs can drastically change how hard they are to numerically integrate.)

Comment: Allright, I am sorry for that. EQ1 and EQ2 were my former notation. I just wanted to make my notation as clear as possible for everybody; this included writing Equation1 and Equation2 instead of EQ1 and EQ2. Thank you for your indications and for the correction, MichaelE2 and Pillsy.

Comment: About the numerical values, just take them as positive-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the expressions matters.  Defining`Equation2` before defining `g[x]` yields

```
Equation2 = f''[x] + 3*(a'[x]/a[x])*f'[x] + D[g[f[x]], f[x]]
(* (3*Derivative[1][a][x]*Derivative[1][f][x])/a[x] + Derivative[1][g][f[x]] 
   + Derivative[2][f][x] *}
```

Note that `D[g[f[x]], f[x]]` has been converted to `Derivative[1][g][f[x]]`.  So, when `g[x]` is subsequently defined, `Derivative[1][g][f[x]]` is unable to interpret it and returns unevaluated.

```
Derivative[1][g][f[x]]
(* Derivative[1][g][f[x]] *)
```

This looks like an additional dependent variable to `NDSolve`, which produces an error message.  On the other hand, if `g[x]` is defined first, then `D[g[f[x]], f[x]]` processes it immediately when `Equation2` is subsequently defined

```
D[g[f[x]], f[x]]
(* Piecewise[{{2*f[x], a2 - x < 0 || (a2 - x <= 0 && a1 - x > 0) || 
   (a1 - x >= 0 && x - x0 >= 0)}, {-n, a1 - x <= 0 && a2 - x >= 0}}, 0] *)
```

producing the desired result.

So, to avoid this problem, define `g[x]` before defining `Equation2`.  Also, remember to

```
Clear[Equation1, Equation2]
```

before starting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @bbgodfrey. You are right, `g[f[x]]` has to be defined before `Equation2` and its derivative is only evaluated when written as D[g[f[x]],f[x]]. However

Comment: @Lloyd  By the way, the calculation becomes very slow when the argument of the square root becomes negative.

Comment: Thanks again, @bbgodfrey. Originally I had my code in the right way you have also insisted and this worked properly (I checked it again by the way). Actually, I also tried for `n>0`, so that the argument of the square root becomes negative and the expression is very slow evaluated, just as you have pointed out. However, the mistake I referred about in my first post **reappears** when _numerically DSolving_ for `g[f[x]]` positive-defined for `x>0`, i.e., taking `n<0`. How could I handle this?

Comment: @Lloyd  Are you saying that `NDSolve::litarg` occurs for `n < 0`?  I cannot reproduce this.  Instead, the `Sqrt` with negative argument reoccurs.

Comment: Not necessarily, @bbgodfrey, this is just another situation I would like to reproduce (apart from the case `n>0`, which gives a negative argument in the `Sqrt`). I mean, as I defined in the Piecewise function one interval in which `g[f[x]]=-n*f[x]`, `n<0 -> g[f[x]]>0`in that interval if `f[x]>0`there. My last attempts in that situation were unsuccesful, but perhaps this is due to mathematical reasons as e.g. the `Sqrt`or discontinuities, I do not know.

Comment: @Lloyd  It does not appear to be a Mathematica problem.

Comment: I will keep on thinking about that. Anyway, thank you so much for your time, @bbgodfrey.